# How to solve rasterstats nodata warning

Tags: rasterio, rasterstats

I am using the `zonal_stats` function in the `rasterstats` package to calculate summary statistics from GeoTiffs containing vegetative index values. The summary statistics come out fine, however with each iteration of the `zonal_stats` function I run, I encounter the warning `UserWarning: Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly warnings.warn("Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly")`

When I created each GeoTIFF file, I set the nodata value as `outband.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)`.  Each geotiff is opened and VI statistics calculated with:

```
    raster = [FILE PATH]
    raster = rasterio.open(raster, mode='r')

    # Assign raster values to numpy nd array
    vi_array = raster.read(1)
    affine = raster.transform

    # Calculate VI stats
    zonal_stats = rasterstats.zonal_stats(shapefile, vi_array, affine=affine,
                                       stats="mean count std median",
                                       geojson_out=True)
```

How does one get rid of this warning message?

Comment: Maybe see here for an answer:  https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/issues/115

Comment: @GBG The numpy version I am using in this environment is 1.21.5

Comment: Post an issue on the rasterstats github page.  Get around the error and use a Python try/except block to catch the exception.  Then use pass to ignore and move on?

Comment: @GBG it's not an exception, it's a warning.

Answer (score 3):

You may have set `nodata` on your raster, but you are not passing that raster to `rasterstats.zonal_stats`, you are passing a numpy array. And numpy arrays don't have a `nodata` property.

Just like you specify the affine transform when passing an array to `rasterstats.zonal_stats` instead of a raster, you can also specify the nodata value:

```
shapefile = [FILE PATH]
raster = [FILE PATH]

with rasterio.open(raster) as src:

    # Assign raster values to numpy nd array
    vi_array = src.read(1)
    affine = src.transform
    nodata = src.nodata

# Calculate VI stats
zonal_stats = rasterstats.zonal_stats(
    shapefile, vi_array, 
    affine=affine, nodata=nodata,
    stats="mean count std median",
    geojson_out=True)
```